# generating stochastic directed networks in R based on a given degree distribution

Tags: r, igraph

I want to generate a random graph in R based on a given degree distribution. I am trying to use the `degree.sequence.game` function in the `igraph` package but it doesn't quite do what I want. I have to questions:

(a) What conditions must be imposed on the in and out degrees for this function to work? For example:

```
ex <- 
    degree.sequence.game(out.deg = c(4,2,17,26,19,17,17,24, 31,32,34,44,40), 
                         in.deg  = c(4,7,13, 13,23,25,26,22,21,38,38,36, 42),
                         method = c("simple"))
```

this works but I do not want loops in my graph, so i tried to set `method = c("simple.multiple") but this returns the error:

```
Error in .Call("R_igraph_degree_sequence_game", as.numeric(out.deg), in.deg,  : 
  At games.c:1072 : No simple directed graph can realize the given degree sequence, Invalid value
```

I'm not quite sure how to fix this...

(b) Is there anyway to generate an ORDERED graph that preserves the order of the links ( I know that networks are meant to be an aggregated object), what I would really like to do is (taking the previous graph as an example):

```
> ex
IGRAPH D--- 13 308 -- Degree sequence random graph
+ attr: name (g/c), method (g/c)
+ edges:
  [1]  3->13  8-> 7  5-> 6  4-> 4 13-> 2 10-> 3 12-> 6  7->12  4-> 6  4->12 11-> 5  7-> 8 10->13  8->10 11-> 5 12-> 6  7-> 6 13-> 9 10->13  3->13 13->13
 [22] 13->10  8-> 4 10->12  7->10  9->13  9-> 2 10-> 9  9->13  9-> 5  9->10 10-> 8 12-> 6 10-> 7 11->12  5->13  4-> 5  9->13 12->10  5-> 2  3->11 11->10
 [43] 12-> 6  6->12 12-> 6 13-> 8  6-> 4 11-> 5 13-> 6 13->13  5->13 13-> 8 10->11 12->11  8->11  8-> 5  7-> 8 12-> 3  1->12  5-> 7  8->11  9-> 4 10->10
 [64] 12->10 12->10 13->10  9->13  9-> 7 10-> 8 12-> 8  9-> 8 13->12 10-> 5  8-> 5  9-> 4  7->10  4-> 7  7->12  7-> 7  4->12 12->10 13->12 10-> 3 13->11
 [85]  6->10 10->10  9-> 4  5->13  2-> 7  4->13  4->11 10-> 5  8-> 4 12-> 3 11->10 13->10  9->13  9->11  9-> 3  3-> 9 12-> 7 10-> 4 13-> 8  5->10  8-> 9
[106] 11-> 4 10-> 3 11-> 4  9->11  4-> 3 12-> 9  6-> 5 10-> 9 11-> 9  8->12 12-> 3  6-> 1 10-> 9 12-> 8  4->13  8-> 9 10-> 8  5->11 13-> 3  5-> 7 11->12
[127] 13-> 7 10-> 7  9-> 6  4-> 7  8-> 8  8->11 11->11  7-> 3 12->11  8->12  6->11 11->11 12->11 13-> 9 13-> 7 12-> 6  6-> 9  9->12 12->13  3-> 2  8->12
[148]  8-> 9  9-> 8  9->12 10->10 12-> 9  5->10  3->13  8->10 11-> 8 13-> 5 13->12 11->10  8->10  3->11  6->11 10->11 12->13 12->11 12-> 8  3->13  7-> 7
+ ... omitted several edges
```

I want to introduce some structure to this, so that if the link 1->3 was followed by 3->4, I would like to know that somehow

Answer (score 1):

a).  The sum of your out degree (308) is one more than the sum of your in degree (307) so it will be impossible to generate a random graph without self loops.  Decrease one of the degrees by one and the code will work.

b).  Are you asking for the edge sequence ordered by source node?  If so, something like this would work,

```
el=data.frame(get.edgelist(ex))
el[with(el,order(X1)),]
```

Comment: are you saying that when the in and out degrees sum to the same number, the option of `method = "simple.no.multiple"` will work? I actually still get the same error with that change...and in fact if i keep the `method = 'simple' ` I still get self loops after making the in degree sum = the out degree sum

Comment: Hmm... that's strange, method="simple" should work if you decrease any of the in degrees by 1.  In my original answer I mixed up the sum of your out and in degrees.  In your example it is out=307 and in=308.  Is that the issue?  If not, what version of igraph are you using?  I believe "simple.no.multiple" will not work with this example because many of your degrees are larger than the number of nodes.